# Rescue clause launched multiple times the same action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The following action

```
def send(server=1)
  @messagelog = Messagelog.new(server_id: params[:server], struttura_id: params[:struttura], user_id: params[:user], chat_id: params[:chat], methodtype_id: params[:methodtype], payload: params[:payload])
  @messagelog.save
  bot = Telegram.bot
  case params[:methodtype]
  when 1
    result =  bot.send_message(chat_id: params[:chat], text: params[:payload])
  when 2 
    result =  bot.send_photo(chat_id: params[:chat], photo: params[:payload])
  when 3 
    result =  bot.send_document(chat_id: params[:chat], document: params[:payload])
  else
  end
  @messagelog.update_attributes(result: result.to_json)
  rescue StandardError => msg
end
```

is invoked via an API and runs 5 times, rescued or not.  Its route is:

```
  namespace  :api  do
    namespace  :v1 do
      post 'send', to: 'messages#send', defaults: { format: :json }
```

The class `class Api::V1::MessagesController < Api::V1::ApibaseController` does not invoke before_actions, however it inherits

```
class Api::V1::ApibaseController < ApplicationController
  before_action :access_control

def access_control
  authenticate_or_request_with_http_token do |token, options|
    @server = Server.where('apikey = ?', token).first
  end
end
```

Where is this multiplication of actions originating from?  The only hiccup from the logs is a statment that:

```
No template found for Api::V1::MessagesController#send, rendering head :no_content
```

If the param are hard-wired to the action, this is also generated, but only one action occurs. Rails 5.2.4

How can this be resolved?

Comment: What are the logs showing exactly, is the same request fired more than once?

Comment: also - could you try renaming send to something else?

Comment: What @Joel_Blum said. Do not call this method `send`. `Object#send` is a message transmission mechanism that is highly leveraged for its dynamics. Overwriting this method is a  very bad idea

Comment: That was effectively the problem.  I usually have a reflex to think about reserved words; must have been dormant...